# Property has no value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't understand why the `TimeBetweenSpawns` property has no value.

Also please let me know if there is a better approach to disable the button for some time after pressing (and then enable it again).

**UnitSpawn.cs**

```
public class UnitSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject position;
    private Button button;

    public void Awake()
    {
        button = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Button").GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void SpawnUnit(Unit unit)
    {
        position = GameObject.Find(unit.SpawnPosition);

        Instantiate(unit.gameObject, position.transform.position, 
            position.transform.rotation);

        button.enabled = false;

        StartCoroutine(WaitTime(unit.TimeBetweenSpawns));
    }

    IEnumerator WaitTime(int timeBetweenSpawns)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSpawns);
        button.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

**Unit.cs**

```
public abstract class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract string SpawnPosition  { get; set; }
    public abstract int MovementSpeed     { get; set; }
    public abstract int TimeBetweenSpawns { get; set; }
    public abstract int Health            { get; set; }
    public abstract int AttackSpeed       { get; set; }
    public abstract int Damage            { get; set; }

    public void Move()
    {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-MovementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

**Unit1.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Unit1 : Unit
{
    public override string SpawnPosition  { get; set; } = 
        "SpawnManager/SpawnPositionForUnit1";
    public override int MovementSpeed     { get; set; } = 3 ;
    public override int TimeBetweenSpawns { get; set; } = 3;
    public override int Health            { get; set; }
    public override int AttackSpeed       { get; set; }
    public override int Damage            { get; set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }
}
```

And a screenshot from the debugger:
[image: Debug]

Comment: Whoever calls `SpawnUnit(Unit unit)`, the issue is possibly there or down the call chain.

Comment: "Property has no value" is very misleading. It has a value; it's 0. Something somewhere is setting it to 0. Maybe make it a read-only property (get rid of the `set`) and see if anything complains.

Comment: How are you generating the GameObject in which Unit is attached? The one that is being used as an argument to SpawnUnit. Is the value of `TimeBetweenSpawns` correct in the inspector?